# 'enum' type breaks in Windows Forms C# designer file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, enums, visual-studio-designer

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this issue before. I'm using C#, .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2013.

I have a custom text box, one that basically just inherits from a standard Windows Forms `TextBox`. On it, there is a property like the following:

```
public EnumName Property { get; set; }
```

The `EnumName` enumeration is defined like this:

```
[Flags]  
public enum EnumName  
{  
     Value1 = 1,  
     Value2 = 2,  
     Value3 = 3  
}
```

When I use my custom control on a form and set the property to `Value3`, the designer actually does:

```
control.EnumName = EnumName.Value1 | EnumName.Value2;
```

This is fine. But lately, when I add a new value to `EnumName` (e.g., `Value4 = 9999`), the designer will instead do this:

```
control.EnumName = EnumName.9999
```

Does anyone know the reason behind this? It's quite frustrating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Flags] attribute, you are saying this enum is a collection of bit flags. This is why 3 is actually 1 | 2.

```
01 = 1
10 = 2
11 = 3
```

3 is both one and two.

You would normally add values for exclusive members of this enum:

```
1   0001
2   0010
4   0100
8   1000
```

A value of 9999 would be the following flags set "10011100001111"

If there is a reason for the flags attribute, leave it and add values like mentioned above. If not, remove the attribute.

Comment: If you wanted to keep the `1,2,3` concept, you could use bitshifting as part of setting your value. `1<<1`, `1<<2`, `1<<3`, etc.